# Rule for orderless function Times

Tags: pattern-matching

I have problems extending a replacement rule.

Schematically, this is the situation: 
I have an expression and a rule, and they work perfectly together.

```
In[1] =  result = expr /.rule
Out[1] = ...
```

Now I want to extend the rule to let it cope with extra multiplication factors. It should be such that

```
In[2] =  5 result - (5 expr /. ruleex)
Out[2] = 0
```

And

```
In[3] =  5 w result - (5 w expr /. ruleex)
Out[3] = 0
```

These are the expression and the rule I am working with:

```
In[4]:=  rule = Times[f[x__][y__], z__] -> Times[-1, q, y, f[x][z]]
In[5]:=  expr = f[-a][s[c, -b]]*f[a][s[-c, b]]
In[6]:=  result = expr /. rule
Out[4]:= -s[c, -b] f[-a][f[a][s[-c, b]]]
```

To make the rule cope with an arbitrary number of multiplicative factors on the left, I guess adding a BlankNullSequence would do.

```
In[7]:=   ruleex = Times[q___, f[x__][y__], z__] -> Times[-1, q, y, f[x][z]];
In[8]:=   expr /.rulex
In[9]:=   5 expr /. ruleex
In[10]:=  5 w expr /. ruleex
Out[5]:=  -s[c, -b] f[-a][f[a][s[-c, b]]]
Out[6]:=  -s[c, -b] f[-a][5, f[a][s[-c, b]]]
Out[7]:=  -s[c, -b] f[-a][5, w, f[a][s[-c, b]]]
```

Out[5] is as expected. The extra factor 5 ends up not at the front of the expression, but somewhere in the in f[a][...]. In Out[7] something similar occurs.

Why does this not work? How can I extend the rule to act in the way I described?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reason why your rule doesn't work is that `Times` is orderless so that the two multiplicative factors at the beginning and end of the expression `5 expr` are not considered distinct.

Your goal seems to be to treat factors that occur to the *left* of the product of `f` differently from factors occurring to the *right*.

This can be done symbolically, but only if you use a different symbol instead of `Times` to describe your non-commutative multiplication. [Fortunately, there is a function pre-defined for that](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NonCommutativeMultiply.html?q=NonCommutativeMultiply&lang=en), it's `NonCommutativeMultiply`:

How to use this depends a little on the details of your problem, but the idea is that you have to start with all your expressions written in this non-commutative way:

```
expr = f[-a][s[c, -b]] ** f[a][s[-c, b]]
```

The `**` replaces normal multiplication here. Now you can manipulate this using a rule of the exact form that you wanted, *except* for the change from `Times` to `**`:

```
ruleex = NonCommutativeMultiply[q___, f[x__][y__], z__] -> 
   NonCommutativeMultiply[-1, q, y, f[x][z]];
```

This yields the following:

```
5 expr /. ruleex

(* ==> 5 (-1) ** s[c, -b] ** f[-a][f[a][s[-c, b]]] *)
```

So the output looks more complicated now, but it has the advantage that you can then work on it further under the assumption of non-commutativity. E.g., you can apply the rule repeatedly using `//.`.

But if you're done with the replacements that depend on the order of factors and want to have a result that has only `Times`, you can end by doing this:

```
5 expr /. ruleex /. NonCommutativeMultiply -> Times

(* ==> -5 s[c, -b] f[-a][f[a][s[-c, b]]] *)
```

Answer (score 3):

Everything Jens wrote is valid, but perhaps you merely want to restrict your `z` pattern a bit.

Consider:

```
ruleex = Times[q___, f[x__][y__], z : f[__][___] ..] :> Times[-1, q, y, f[x][z]];

expr = f[-a][s[c, -b]]*f[a][s[-c, b]];

5 w expr /. ruleex
```

> ```
> -5 w s[c, -b] f[-a][f[a][s[-c, b]]]
> ```