# Why does the name of a pattern affect the result of a transformation rule?

Tags: evaluation, pattern-matching, replacement

I was playing a little dirty, trying to get a template for defining a `Curl[]` operator.

I wrote the following rule, which I knew was going to spit out a few errors, because all symbols there (including the lists), were undefined:

```
Cross[{d[1], d[2], d[3]}, {2, 3, 4}] /. Times[a_, b_] -> b[[a]]
```

Notwithstanding the errors, the result I got was what I wanted:

```
(* {d[2][[4]] + d[3][[-3]], d[1][[-4]] + d[3][[2]], d[1][[3]] + d[2][[-2]]} *)
```

with a few more replacements, you can almost see the `Curl[]` operator materializing.

Sadly, I forgot that the symbol `a` was  already in use in may main `.nb`, so I changed it to `c`. Look:

```
Cross[{d[1], d[2], d[3]}, {2, 3, 4}] /. Times[c_, b_] -> b[[c]]
```

But now the results are completely different!

```
(* {(-3)[[d[3]]] + 4[[d[2]]], (-4)[[d[1]]] + 2[[d[3]]], (-2)[[d[2]]] + 3[[d[1]]]} *)
```

Wow!

I `Traced` the evaluation, and could easily find out where the both processes started to differ, but I couldn't understand why.

Any ideas?

Comment: You are using immediate rules, so there is a chance that `b` or `c` had prior values. Try with delayed rules instead, they scope their variables properly.

Comment: Hi @LeonidShifrin! I already tried that, and starting a fresh kernel ... nothing more came to my mind.

Comment: There can also be an issue with the ordering, since it is different for `b,a` and `b,c`, and `Times` is `Orderless`. Some unwanted reorderings may happen based on variable names.

Comment: Would it be possible to copy the original .nb and change the symbol a to something else to verify that original results return?  Sometimes a small tweak somewhere else can have side-effects?  If the original results do not come back, that would indicate that the symbol change from a to c is not the problem.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin Ohh If the evaluator reorders the pattern, that could be the issue

Comment: @Fred No, that is not the case

Comment: This talk illustrates the effect of Orderless in the pattern matcher, http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/6999/

Comment: @FaysalAberkane Thanks Faysal! I will take a look at it tomorrow.

Comment: Related: [(7519)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7519/121)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just my little cent (yeah, cent is uncountable, there are too much of them around, so what)

`Orderless` (quite similarly to [Flat](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/306/109)) not only affects the automatic reordering of arguments. It also affects the pattern matching.

In here, both things are responsible for the behaviour. Not both together, but both by themselves. @R.M has already explained how the reordering of the patterns can ruin the party.

As to the second issue, when the pattern matcher is faced with matching an expression with an `Orderless` head, it knows it will have to check all combinations of orders of the patterns (until it finds one). So, for example

```
Hold[2 "a"] /. Hold[i_String j_Integer] :> {i, j}
```

> {"a", 2}

A nice application of this behaviour is in @Mr.Wizard's [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/8160/109)

So, no matter the actual stored ordering of the patterns, it just gets ignored when matching

In conclusion, I support @R.M's advice on not to rely ever on the ordering of arguments of an `Orderless` head

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the links!

Answer (score 14):

This is due to the `Orderless` attribute of `Times`. When you write `Times[c_, b_]`, it automatically gets reordered to `Times[b_, c_]` even before any of the rules have been read. The reordering is in the sense of `OrderedQ`. Compare:

```
OrderedQ[{Pattern[b, Blank[]], Pattern[c, Blank[]]}]
(* True *)
OrderedQ[{Pattern[c, Blank[]], Pattern[b, Blank[]]}]
(* False *)
```

Once you realize that, you can begin to see why `b[[c]]` wouldn't give the right answer.

If you compare the two results closely, you'll see that each term is just flipped inside out (loosely speaking). i.e., `d[2][[4]]` becomes `4[[d[2]]]`, which is in accordance with `b` and `c` being flipped by the reordering. To further confirm this is the case, change the rule to `Times[c_, b_] -> c[[b]]` and you'll get the same answer as in the first case.

In general, it is probably not a good idea to use rely on the order of arguments in an orderless function for further processing/rules unless if the order doesn't matter in the latter case too (e.g. changing `Times` to `Plus`).

Comment: Ok OK blame me. For some reason I thought the Orderless attribute didn't play a role in patterns. Shame on me. Please someone comfort me saying that I am not completely stupid.

Comment: @Verde You can take comfort in the fact that 99% is less than 100% :)

Comment: Ok. I'll take that as it were almost but not quite entirely unlike an insult

Comment: @Verde Hey, 99% insult is less than 100% insult :D :D

Comment: @Verde, the sad fact is that there is one person in the world who __is__ completely stupid.

Comment: @Fred Who. Who is in the first base?

Comment: @Verde, just check my troubleshooting comment above to see who beats Who.

Comment: @FredDanielKline C'mon. I'm the one sliding dangerously here.