# Pattern matching an expression involving Times

Tags: pattern-matching, hold

I'm trying to write a Mathematica function that will format expressions according to my preferences, for example displaying `(5 c x)/Sqrt[2]` as `5/Sqrt[2] c x`instead.
While attempting this I have come across some pattern matching behaviour that I don't understand, which reveals some holes in my understanding of the evaluation process.

As a simple example, consider the following:

```
Times[a, b, f[], c] /. Times[x__, f[], y__] :> {{x}, f[], {y}}
```

> ```
> {{a}, f[], {b, c}}
> ```

I expected that this would output

> ```
> {{a, b}, f[], {c}}
> ```

A `Trace` gives the following output:

```
Column@Trace[Times[a, b, f[], c] /. Times[x__, f[], y__] :> {{x}, f[], {y}}]
```

> ```
> {a b f[] c,a b c f[]}
>
> {{x__ f[] y__,f[] x__ y__},f[] x__ y__:>{{x},f[],{y}},f[] x__ y__:>{{x},f[],{y}}}
>
> a b c f[]/. f[] x__ y__:>{{x},f[],{y}} 
>
> {{a},f[],{b,c}}
> ```

Clearly `Times` is evaluating and shuffling its arguments to a standard form.
I will obviously have to apply `HoldForm` or similar, but even at this stage I don't understand why the `ReplaceAll` as shown in the `Trace` outputs this result. (EDIT: To be clear, I don't understand why or how Mathematica has gotten `a b c f[]` to match `f[] x__ y__`, or why `a` is matched by `x__` and `b`, `c` are matched by `y__`).
What approach should I apply to understand why this is the result?

Next, I try again while holding expressions:

```
HoldForm[Times[a, b, f[], c]] /. HoldPattern[Times[x__, f[], y__]] :> {{x}, f[], {y}}
```

> ```
> {{a},f[],{b,c}}
> ```

And I still get the undesired result.
Here is the `Trace`:

```
Trace[HoldForm[Times[a, b, f[], c]] /. HoldPattern[Times[x__, f[], y__]] :> {{x}, f[], {y}}]
```

> ```
> {HoldPattern[x__ f[] y__]:>{{x},f[],{y}},HoldPattern[x__ f[] y__]:>{{x},f[],{y}}}
>
> a b f[] c/. HoldPattern[x__ f[] y__]:>{{x},f[],{y}}
>
> {{a},f[],{b,c}}
> ```

Now it *appears* as if `Times` is not shuffling its arguments, but somehow along the way the `b` has still been matched by `y__`.
What is happening under the hood here?
And why is `Trace` not showing it?

Finally now I remembered `Verbatim`:

```
HoldForm[Times[a, b, f[], c]] /. Verbatim[Times][x__, f[], y__] :> {{x}, f[], {y}}
```

> ```
> {{a,b},f[],{c}}
> ```

which gives the desired result.
Why does `Verbatim` work better here than `HoldPattern`?
I have been told before that `Verbatim` is for "escaping the pattern matcher", but the argument `Times` of `Verbatim` hardly seems like something that the pattern matcher should care about.

So to summarise:

- How do I understand what is happening under the hood when pattern matching with `Times`?
- Why did `Verbatim` work better than `HoldPattern`?

EDIT:

Thinking more about this line:

```
HoldForm[Times[a, b, f[], c]] /. HoldPattern[Times[x__, f[], y__]] :> {{x}, f[], {y}}
```

I don't understand how shuffling the arguments of `Times[x__, f[], y__]` could cause `y__` to match `b c`, since `b` and `c` in the expression are separated by `f[]`.
Is the pattern matcher able to shuffle the arguments of the expression even though it is contained in `HoldForm`?

Comment: This is not an explanation, but is there some reasons why you dont want temporary Block Times, like in Block[{Times},Times[a, b, f[], c] /. Times[x__, f[], y__] :> {{x}, f[], {y}}]

Comment: I had considered that, and will probably ultimately incorporate it, but for now I'd like to know exactly what's going on under the hood.

Comment: ¨Print[g[a, b, f[], c] /.   g[x__, f[], y__] :> {{x},     f[], {y}}]; SetAttributes[g, Orderless]; Print[ g[a, b, f[], c] /. g[x__, f[], y__] :> {{x}, f[], {y}}]´

Comment: So `Times` is `Orderless` and so its arguments are automatically sorted into canonical order? I still don't see why `a` and `b`, `c` get matched by different blank sequences.

Comment: Also consider `Print[Times[a, b, f[], c] /. 
  Times[Longest[x__], f[], y__] :> {{x}, f[], {y}}]; Print[
 Times[a, b, f[], c] /. 
  Times[Shortest[x__], f[], y__] :> {{x}, f[], {y}}]`

Comment: Ahah! From http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Orderless.html: "In matching patterns with Orderless functions, all possible orders of arguments are tried."

Comment: Now all that remains is to understand `Verbatim` vs. `HoldPattern` in this case.

Comment: Related/duplicate: [(7519)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7519)

Answer (score 7):

Because of the `Orderless` property of `Times`, the following

```
Times[a, b, f[], c] /. Times[x__, f[], y__] :> {{x}, f[], {y}}
```

gets turned into

```
a b c f[]/. f[] x__ y__:>{{x},f[],{y}}
```

through [canonical ordering](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sort.html).
Furthermore, the `Orderless` attribute of `Times` *in the pattern* means that ["all possible orders of arguments are tried"](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Orderless.html).
Additionally, ["If no explicit `Shortest` or `Longest` is given, ordinary expression patterns are normally effectively assumed to be `Shortest[p]`"](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Shortest.html).

So the pattern matcher will shuffle `f[] x__ y__` until the `f[]` gets to the end, whereupon `x__` will match `a` as `Shortest[x__]` and `y__` will match `b c` as `Shortest[y__]`.

In the next example

```
HoldForm[Times[a, b, f[], c]] /. HoldPattern[Times[x__, f[], y__]] :> {{x}, f[], {y}}
```

the expression is held, and the pattern is held, but even though it does not evaluate, the pattern matcher still sees that `Times` is `Orderless`, and so all possible orders or arguments are tried, and the `x__` and `y__` patterns are still treated as `Shortest`. So the best match is still

> ```
> {{a},f[],{b,c}}
> ```

When `Verbatim` is used:

```
HoldForm[Times[a, b, f[], c]] /. Verbatim[Times][x__, f[], y__] :> {{x}, f[], {y}}
```

the `Times` head is no longer "active", and so the pattern matcher will not consider any attributes of `Times`.
The desired result is then obtained.

EDIT:

Here I will add insights on how to better approach this in the future.

- Preventing evaluation does not prevent the pattern matcher from looking at attributes of heads.
- Using `Block` can prevent the special properties of heads from confusing the issue.
- When using multiple `BlankSequence`, one must consider the greediness of the pattern matcher.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe someone can come up with a good explanation why this is a bug, but I believe it is more a feature. It is not specifically bound to `Times`, but this works for every function with the `Orderless` attribute.

That being said, we can check whether or not the pattern matching and replacing leaks evaluation, because this would be the only reason for a reordering of the arguments: The function gets evaluated in the process of replacement. Therefore, let's start simple

```
test[___] := Throw["Error"];
SetAttributes[test, Attributes[Times]]

Hold[test[a, b, f[], c]] /. 
  HoldPattern[test[x__, f[], y__]] :> {{x}, f[], {y}}
(* Hold[{{a}, f[], {b, c}}] *)
```

Still reorders the arguments and it seems nothing gets evaluated. It almost seems this is intentional. Maybe it has proven to be required for some practical reasons.

Finally, in your current example, you pattern gets pretty much fixed with the appearance of `f[]`. Therefore, a shorter solution to the problem is to skip the `Times` head completely

```
HoldForm[Times[a,b,f[],c]]/._[x__,f[],y__]:>{{x},f[],{y}}
(* {{a,b},f[],{c}} *)
```

or if you insist, then it is enough to hide it a bit

```
HoldForm[Times[a,b,f[],c]]/.(_:Times)[x__,f[],y__]:>{{x},f[],{y}}
(* {{a,b},f[],{c}} *)
```

Comment: Thanks. Using `Throw` is a useful debugging tool. Unfortunately here the problem lies in the pattern matcher, outside of the main evaluation loop. I know there are many solutions, but I don't even want to use the pattern matcher until I can understand why it does what it does.

Comment: What do you mean by `(_:Times)` I am not able to figure it out.