# MatchQ failing in some cases with Hold

Tags: pattern-matching, hold, attributes, placeholder

Could someone clarify why the first of these `MatchQ` finds a match whereas the second does not?  (I'm using version 10.0, in case that matters.)

```
MatchQ[Hold[x + 2 y], Hold[x + 2 _]]
(*True*)
MatchQ[Hold[x + 2 y + 0], Hold[x + 2 _ + 0]]
(*False*)
```

EDIT: The conclusion below is that when encountering an `Orderless` function (here `Plus`), the pattern matcher does not test for all possible orderings of arguments but rather sorts the pattern's constant arguments and allows blanks `_` to appear in arbitrary places within that list.  This reordering disregards `Hold`.  On the other hand `Hold` does keep the order of the arguments of the expression fixed, so `Hold[x+2y+0]` is compared (with fixed argument order) to `Hold[0+x+2_]`, `Hold[0+2_+x]` and `Hold[2_+0+x]`, none of which match.

Comment: related: [Pattern matching an expression involving Times](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/94422/5478)

Comment: Closely related: [Pattern matching on Orderless functions inside Hold](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/30152/pattern-matching-on-orderless-functions-inside-hold)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### UPDATE

[That question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/94432/280) is by the essence an exact duplicate of this one. The [explanation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/94569/280) given by Mr.Wizard means that the pattern-matcher is NOT capable to handle situations when an unevaluated function with `Orderless` attribute is wrapped by `Hold`. So this is indeed a gedanken functionality.

The pattern-matcher works on the base of the assumption that `Orderless` attribute is already applied and the arguments are sorted in the canonical order:

```
ClearAll[o]
SetAttributes[o, Orderless]
MatchQ[Hold[o[y, x, a]], Hold[o[_, x, a]]]
MatchQ[Hold[Evaluate@o[y, x, a]], Hold[o[_, x, a]]]
```

> ```
> False
>
> True
> ```

In the light of this the Documentation [statement](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Orderless.html)

> In matching patterns with `Orderless` functions, all possible orders of
>   arguments are tried.

means that actually only all possible *positions* of the `Blank`s in the pattern are tried but other arguments *in the pattern* are preliminarily sorted in the fixed canonical order. This is evident from the following:

```
MatchQ[Hold[o[y, a, x]], Hold[o[_, x, a]]]
MatchQ[Hold[o[y, x, a]], Hold[o[_, x, a]]]
MatchQ[Hold[o[y, a, x]], Hold[o[x, _, a]]]
MatchQ[Hold[o[y, a, x]], Hold[o[x, a, _]]]
```

> ```
> True
>
> False
>
> True
>
> True
> ```

In the other words, `Hold` prevents applying `Orderless` attribute in the sense that it prevents sorting of the arguments in the canonical order, but it does not prevent action of this attribute in the pattern (i.e. all possible positions of the `Blank`s are indeed tried).

---

### Original answer

This behavior is definitely comes from the `Orderless` attribute of `Plus` and reproduces for arbitrary function having this attribute. As can be seen from the following, without `Hold` the pattern matches regardless of the order of the arguments due to `Orderless` attribute of `o`:

```
ClearAll[o]
SetAttributes[o, Orderless]
MatchQ[o[y, x, a], o[_, x, a]]
MatchQ[o[y, a, x], o[_, a, x]]
MatchQ[o[y, x, a], o[_, a, x]]
```

> ```
> True
>
> True
>
> True
> ```

But when we wrap the expressions by `Hold` something breaks - now it does not match even when the order of the arguments is identical:

```
MatchQ[Hold[o[y, x, a]], Hold[o[_, x, a]]]
```

> ```
> False
> ```

Surprisingly, it does match if we reorder arguments in the both expressions:

```
MatchQ[Hold[o[y, a, x]], Hold[o[_, a, x]]]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

I suspect that we have a bug in the pattern matcher because this behavior cannot be explained by the documented meaning of the `Orderless` attribute.

Answer (score 3):

You can put a `Verbatim` on the Plus:

```
MatchQ[Hold[x + 2 y + 0], Hold[Verbatim[Plus][x, 2 _, 0]]] (* True *)
```

Another way:

```
expr = Inactivate[x + 2 y + 1];
form = Inactivate[x + 2 _ + 1];
MatchQ[expr, IgnoringInactive@form] (* True *)
```

Comment: `HoldAllComplete` is an attribute, probably you mean `HoldComplete`.

Comment: I know, but you can use it as a function.

Comment: `HoldAllComplete` as a function works exactly as `List`: it does not have any `Hold*` attribute.

Comment: Oh sorry, yes HoldComplete was what I meant.

Comment: Interesting.  But why does using `Verbatim` make the match succeed?  (Or rather, why is the match failing without `Verbatim`?)

Comment: You need the verbatim to stop mathematica from moving around the arguments in plus I think

Comment: Ok, after reading answers to the duplicate question, the explanation for `Verbatim` working is that the head of the pattern is then `Verbatim[Plus]`, which does not have the `Orderless` attribute.  Thus the pattern matcher does not sort arguments `x`, `2_`, `0` and it succeeds because the order of arguments on the lhs and rhs match.

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch exactly right